# SQL Query to get number of appearence of a integer in Columns Values (Or Tips to do it in code)

Tags: c#, sql, datatable, oledb

The title is a little confusing but I couldn't find a better one.
here is what i want to do. I have a Table of this form:

---

Name | Gender | Answers

Tom | Male | 1,2,3

Kate | Female | 1,4

John | Male | 2,4

Maggy | Female | 1,3

---

I have 2 questions:

1) If there a query to get the number of integers appearing in the Answers column?

In our example:

Answer | Count

1 | 3

2 | 2

3 | 2

4 | 2

2)If the above is possible is there a way to breakdown by gender:

In our example:

Gender | Answer | Count

Male | 1 | 1

Male | 2 | 2

Male | 3 | 1

Female | 1 | 2

Female | 3 | 2

I hope I was clear.

I am using C#, and reading data from an excel sheet using an OleDB Connection.

If there is no way to do it via SQL Query, how to do it in C# code. (I use a Datatable to fill the data I read)

Thank you very much for any help

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work?  BTW, your non-normalised table is a bad idea!

Comment: +1 Mitch -- if the answers are normalized, this query is simple.

Comment: Hi, I have tried to query them as a single value, save them as a string and try to go through all the characters, save the integers, count them... but this is becoming too messy and I'm getting a little confused. I was just wondering if it can be done my a query. I have no choice but to use a non-normalised table because this is how i get it. Thanks you for any tips you can give me

Comment: The data is not first normal form (NFNF) and is hard to query with SQL. If you get the data in NFNF then scrub the data to transform it to at least 1NF ("normalized"), preferably 5NF or better ("fully normalized"). This is possibly easier to achieve using your 3GL of choice or in SQL such as suggested by @Rikon. But the point is that you do this *once* then subsequently query the normalized data only.

Answer (score 1):

You should not store multiple values in a field, you should normalise the table using a separate table for the answers:

```
Person:
Id  Name   Gender
1   Tom    Male
2   Kate   Female
3   John   Male
4   Maggy  Female

Answer:
Id Answer
1  1
1  2
1  3
2  1
2  4
3  2
3  4
4  1
4  3
```

Now you can easily get the number of answers using `count`

```
selecct p.Name, count(*) as Cnt
from Person p
inner join Answer a on a.Id = p.Id
group by p.Name
```

You can just as easily group by gender and answer:

```
selecct p.Gender, a.Answer, count(*)
from Person p
inner join Answer a on a.Id = p.Id
group by p.Gender, a.Answer
```

Answer (score 1):

(I'll try to answer this in MSSql)

You can manufacture a split function in sql like the example seen here: http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=50648

Note that you can modify the first example to this (it's the GroupOn code, which would be your "male" or "female" element):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split
(
    @RowData nvarchar(2000),
    @SplitOn nvarchar(5),
          @GroupOn nvarchar(100)
)  

RETURNS @RtnValue table 
(
    Id int identity(1,1),
    Data nvarchar(100),
          GroupOn nvarchar(100)
) 
AS  
BEGIN 

Declare @Cnt int
Set @Cnt = 1

While (Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)>0)
Begin
    Insert Into @RtnValue (data)
    Select 
        Data = ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@RowData,1,Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)-1)))

    Set @RowData = Substring(@RowData,Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)+1,len(@RowData))
    Set @Cnt = @Cnt + 1
End

Insert Into @RtnValue (data, @GroupOn)
Select Data = ltrim(rtrim(@RowData))

Return
END
```

And then you could just count and group on accordingly.

**EDIT**
Fixed a misspelling above.

Answer (score 0):

This query is for question 2. It can be trivially modified to match result from question 1.

```
    declare @t table
    (
        name varchar(50),
        gender varchar(50),
        answers varchar(50)
    )

    insert into @t
    select 'Tom', 'Male', '1,2,3'
    union
    select 'Kate', 'Female', '1,4'
    union
    select 'John', 'Male', '2,4'
    union
    select 'Maggy', 'Female', '1,3'

    select 
        gender, answer, count = count(*)
    from
    (
        select
            gender, 
            -- here t2.c is an xml column, which holds values of this sort <a>1</a>
            -- 'data(.)' gets the value from the <a> tag
            answer = cast(t2.c.query('data(.)') as varchar)
        from
        (
            select 
                name, gender, 
                -- represent answers in the xml, proper for xquery node function
                -- for example <root><a>1</a><a>2</a></root>
                answers = cast('<root><a>' + replace(answers, ',', '</a><a>') + '</a></root>' as xml)
            from @t
        ) t1
        -- xquery nodes function reads the xml and
        -- in this case for each tag <a> it returns a separate row
        cross apply answers.nodes('/root/a') t2(c)
    ) t
    group by gender, answer
    order by gender desc, answer
```

Note: the result will not match the one that you provided in part 2, because your result is not corresponding to your example data, if I understood your problem correctly.